# jQuery BBQ, How to detect a repeat click, which doesn't trigger a hashchange

Tags: jquery, browser-history, jquery-bbq

I'm using the jQuery plugin hashchange: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

```
$(function(){
    $(window).hashchange( function(){
      // location.hash
    })
    $(window).hashchange(); // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
});
```

This works great the problem is if you click on a link more than once:

```
<a href="#/p/31">im a link</a>
```

the hashchange doesn't refire which I want so that when the user clicks on a link more than once I can refresh the data. Is that possible?

Any ideas on how I can detect a repeat click?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the hash before you apply it, and/or use a flag.